# Package Control: The dependency 'markupsafe' is not currently installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, package, sublimetext3, package-control

While trying to install [Git​Gutter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GitGutter) on [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com), I get the following in Console:

```
ignored packages updated to: ["GitGutter", "Vintage"]
reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
Package Control: The dependency 'markupsafe' is not currently installed; installing...
Package Control: Error downloading package. HTTP exception BadStatusLine ('') downloading https://bitbucket.org/teddy_beer_maniac/sublime-text-dependency-markupsafe/get/0.23.0.zip.
error: Package Control

Unable to download markupsafe. Please view the console for more details.
Package Control: The dependency 'markupsafe' could not be installed or updated
ignored packages updated to: ["Vintage"]
reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
```

I have downloaded the dependency needed from [this link](https://bitbucket.org/teddy_beer_maniac/sublime-text-dependency-markupsafe/get/0.23.0.zip) as a `.zip` file and now that is in my `Downloads` folder
[image]
What are the next steps and where should I place that file in order to have `markupsafe` manually installed.
**P.S:** I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and planning to use sublime for Python developement.

Comment: Have you tried to manually run the command *Package Control: Satisfy Dependencies*?

Comment: I think the key there is the line about a bad status line while downloading the code from BitBucket. Perhaps there was a transient problem on the server or something. Does it still not work?

Comment: solved...it was because of a problem with my network connection

Answer (score 0):

For the people like me coming here in the future, there are several issues on Githib regarding this, the crux of them being that there was a problem with Github and `Package Control` which caused this.

They are being tracked here: https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1334

One possible fix that worked for me was to update the user settings of Package Control and add the following lines:

```
"downloader_precedence":  
{  
    "linux": [ "curl","wget","urllib"],  
    "osx":   ["curl","wget","urllib"]  
}
```